# Is there a way for Uncrustify to return the style differences and not to correct them?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, coding-style, xcode5, uncrustify

I'm using Uncrustify for some code styling in Obj-C, but I want to notify the developer what he is doing wrong and let him modify the code

Is there a way to use this in order to get the code style differences?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything built into Uncrustify, but you can do it in combination with the diff tool: redirect output from Uncrustify to a file and create a patch file with diff.

```
uncrustify -f file1 -o file2
diff -u file1 file2  >> mypatch.patch
```